# How to test if function does not throw exception?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, nunit, nsubstitute

I have this function and test:

```
public void SaveForWeb ()
{
    UpdateGameState();
    try
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(Helper.EXP_KEY, experience);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(Helper.SCORE_KEY, score);
        // other properties that need to be saved in PlayerPrefs

        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Log(ex.Message);
    }
}

[Test]
[Category(Helper.TEST_CATEGORY_SAVE_FOR_WEB)]
public void SaveForWebTest ()
{
    // arrange
    var slgdController = FakeSaveLoadGameDataController();
    TestDelegate myDelegate = () => {};

    // act
    slgdController.SaveForWeb();

    // assert
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(myDelegate);
}
```

But I feel there is no connection between the assertion and the call of `SaveForWeb()` function.

Note: SaveForWeb() uses PlayerPrefs from the Unity3D API which might throw PlayerPrefsException if the local file exceedes 1 MB.

Is this the right way to assert if function does not throw exception?

Comment: You don't need to assert that a function does not throw an exception in a unit test. By default, if an exception is thrown in a unit test then the unit test will fail due to an unexpected exception.

Comment: Yes its a duplicate but ok, somebody from the Unity3D community might find it useful.

Comment: Nothing wrong with duplicates if useful (and presumably innocent) :p

Comment: So I read the xUnit issue below- and boy was it spicy. In short- they did get rid of DoesNotThrow. I guess I am in the opinionated camp that it should have stayed- however it's far too late for that. For those looking for a way to explictly declare this in your tests, you can also check this using Record.Exception or trying to get an exception- if no exception occurs it will return null:
var exception = Record.Exception(() => act());
Assert.Null(exception);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to assert if the method doesn't throw. I know you're using NUnit, but there's a [xUnit issue](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/188) that describes why you don't need to assert it.

However, if you want to be explicit, you can do:

```
[Test]
[Category(Helper.TEST_CATEGORY_SAVE_FOR_WEB)]
public void SaveForWebTest ()
{
    // arrange
    var slgdController = FakeSaveLoadGameDataController();

    Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => slgdController.SaveForWeb());
}
```

Comment: Some of the other answers work but this approach gives the best error message when it fails.

Answer (score 6):

If it does not throw an exception your code should simply work and reach the end of the test-method. So you can add an `Assert.IsTrue(true)` at end which is only called **if** the method ran without any error. Otherwise (if an exception occurs) the test will immediately stop and return false.

EDIT: You do not even need a call to `Assert.IsTrue`, the test will also succeed if it reaches the end. However static analysis may produce a warning when your test has no assertions.

Comment: So you want to say that if SaveForWeb() throws exception it will stop the execution of the test at that line where it broke?

Comment: Yeap, if an exception occurs the test will immediately stop and return false.

Comment: I agree with the argument in your EDIT but when you don't use any `Assert` statements in the test then static analysis tools emit a warning something like *Add at least one assertion to this test case*.

Answer (score 4):

In my tests, I just make no assertion. If an exception is thrown, the test would failed cause you don't have an `ExpectedException` attribute or so.

```
Assert.IsTrue(true)
```

is meaningless imho.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned the unit test will fail automatically. However, if you really did want to write an assertion for this try something like this.

```
[Test]
[Category(Helper.TEST_CATEGORY_SAVE_FOR_WEB)]
public void SaveForWebTest ()
{
    // arrange
    var slgdController = FakeSaveLoadGameDataController();
    TestDelegate myDelegate = () => {};

    // act
    try
    {
        slgdController.SaveForWeb();
        Assert.IsTrue(true) // Not Actually necessary as should still pass
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.Fail("Expected no exception, but got: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give your Unit tests more meaningful names. This way, you can actually understand from the test what is going wrong:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SaveForWeb_WhenGameControllerIsOk_DoesNotThrowException()
    {
        // Arrange
        var controller = FakeSaveLoadGameDataController();

        // Act
        controller.SaveForWeb();

        // Assert - Will fail by exceptionThrown
    }

    [TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof(ReallyBadException))]
    public void SaveForWeb_WhenGameControllerThrowsException_ThrowsException()
    {
        // Arrange
        var controller = new FakeSaveLoadGameDataControllerWithException();

        // Act
        controller.SaveForWeb();
    }
```